# Polymorphic relations taggable_type

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphism, relationship

since i am working on existing database and can't change Data how do i insert in the relation that the taggable_type is (Firm) and not the default (App\firm)

Thanks

Comment: Show code of how do you insert it now.

Comment: i dont insert i just display it. Firm::with('tags')->get();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was in the documentations :s

[here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#custom-polymorphic-types)